# What sort of events could end up consuming 'sys' time on OSX and not on Linux?

Tags: performance, macos

A program of mine that 'computes', on OS/X, shows a time like:

```
real    0m10.883s
user    0m6.924s
sys     0m3.957s
```

On a nearby Linux system, in contrast, I see:

```
real    0m7.480s
user    0m7.172s
sys     0m0.280s
```

To make matters worse, this situation arrived after rewriting one particular algorithm, and neither the new nor the old does any obvious system-call-ish stuff.

Some poking around with dapptrace and iprofiler failed to turn up anything. This is all 10.8.2, xcode 4.2. The code in question is C++.

The code here is not (yet) small enough to post here. I can say that the area where things changed has STL vectors and maps in it. However, dapptrace was not revealing.

procsystime, however, reveals that 'madvise' is the system call at the root of this evil.

I'm going to vote to close this and write a new question based on what I've learned.

Comment: Doesn't meet question guidelines; not enough info.  We're probably gonna need to see some code.

Comment: do you do anything like call a random function? have you looked at a process sample (from activity monitor)?

Comment: strace the program on both systems and diff it. It's a longshot but you might find a clue in there.

Comment: strace isn't on OSX, the alternative, dapptrace, hasn't cooperated yet.

Comment: FWIW, I've spent many happy hours looking at the output of callgrind, iprofiler, 'control-c sampling', etc, and nothing has revealed itself yet.

Comment: Linux has some vsyscalls, like `gettimeofday` and `clock_gettime` (which are user-space), I don't think they are accounted as system calls in such a measurement.

Comment: @DanielKO Linux doesn't matter here. Linux is good. The problem is OSX.

Comment: @bmargulies: Did I read your question incorrectly? You seem to be comparing the results on a Linux system versus on an OSX system; I'm giving one possible reason why a given program might spend less time in kernel-mode (due to vsyscall mechanisms) than systems without such a mechanism (where equivalent functionality might require a true system call).

Comment: @DanielKO, no, I read you backwards.

Answer (score 1):

"sys" time (short for "system") represents cpu time spent running kernel code.  Obviously, your program is relying on some facility that is implemented in the OSX kernel that is not implemented in the Linux kernel.  My guess is that you're using some library that has different implementations on the two respective platforms.

Another possibility might be the result of cpu time being accounted differently--they are entirely separate operating systems, after all.  Their internal instrumentation is going to be different from each other.

Impossible to say for sure without more info about your program -- care to post any source code?

Comment: If and when I come up with a cut-down example of this little muddle, I'll edit the question. I was hoping that someone could suggest some like candidate for a library function with this characteristic.

Comment: @bmargulies  It could be as simple as incidental contact with any calls that wind up being handled by the kernel on linux.  Any kind of i/o, be it disk, swap, memory, filesystem, nic, etc it literally could be anything.  It's also possible that the time is merely being accounted differently or it could be the result of hardware diversity.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you see mysterious sys time, `procsystime` is your friend. It provides a concise summary of system time usage.
2. Beware of `free`. On OS/X, `free` has a fondness for `madvice`. It might be a bug, it might be a feature, but code that runs lickety-split on Linux can run much more slowly on OS/X due to `free` calling `madvise`.